# Circle containing points

Tags: geometry

Find all such positive integers $n\geq2$ that there exists a set of n points on a plane, every one of which lies outside of some circle containing all the other points and having the center in one of these points.

Could you please help me? I don't even understand how am I supposed to create such a circle... As "every one of which lies outside of some circle", how, at the same time, the circle can contain "all the other points"?

Comment: "and having the middle in one of them" dangles in your sentence.  There's something in one of the points?

Comment: What does "having the middle in one of them" mean? Does middle mean centre? To what kind of object does "them" refer?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, changed.

Comment: Could you respond on whether I decrypted the task correctly

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot about it... Yes, I believe you understood it correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you intepret it such:
Find all n such that we can have n points $p_i$, and n circles $C_t$, such that if $j\neq k$, then $p_j$ is contained in $C_k$, and each $C_q$ has a point $p_q$ at its center.

Then for every even $2\leq n$, we can place the points at the corners of a regular n-gon.

Proof: There is for every point a diagonalically opposite point which is further away then the others

Comment: Thank you but is this proof enough? I mean, seems kind of short for a problem like that.

Comment: No its not. I will solve it tommorow if noone else does

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you do. Looking forward, then :)

Comment: Could you please try to prove this as you stated? I can't...

Comment: Dont have time, formulate it better and someone else might